# Drupal Pager Error Causing WSOD When Viewing Term or Edit Term

Tags: views

I have recently been through the ordeal of updating D6 to D7. Things went better than I had previously encountered but I have a problem thats really holding me back and I can't work out how to sort it.

When I try to view a `taxonomy/term/` page or edit a term I get a WSOD. I managed to show the error which was:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function use_pager() on a non-object in /home/oddeba/public_html/onlinebanter.co.uk/sites/all/modules/views/includes/view.inc on line 690

Line 690:

```
    function init_pager() {
         if (empty($this->query->pager)) {
           $this->query->pager = $this->display_handler->get_plugin('pager');

        Line 690>>>  if ($this->query->pager->use_pager()) {
            $this->query->pager->set_current_page($this->current_page);
           }
```

Things are fine with Views disabled. I can for the life of me think how I needed a pager about my taxonomy before.

Could anyone suggest anything that could be causing it?

Comment: Is this a D6 view upgraded to D7?

Comment: reverted taxonomy default view and things are fine now :) dont mind me.

Comment: Check Drupal log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ever run into a WSOD error, follow the directions here and it will generally tell you the file name and the line number that is causing the WSOD. Or, it will tell you that your server resources are too limited (out of memory).

Here are the instructions:

http://drupal.org/node/158043

Or just Google 'Drupal WSOD' and it's the first link on the SERP.

Comment: As he says above, the problem is not a generic WSOD but a specific error.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this `use_pager()` problem again. This time with the `frontpage` view. I solved it by going to the view, opening the pager settings and choosing the same option again, then saving the view.